# Cannot find a differ supporting object Error Angular2

Tags: angular

Trying to get Values (Array of Objects) from Local Storage and Displaying using `*ngIf` but angular throws error of `Cannot find a differ supporting object` . 
here is Plnkr throwing error

http://plnkr.co/edit/qgrOmRlUcAZq1spGALEa?p=preview

```
 <template ngFor #permissionvar [ngForOf]="LocalStorageData">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu" *ngIf="permissionvar.root_permission_name == 'School Setting'">
        <a (click)="Schoolsettings()">
            <i class="fa fa-gears"></i>
            <span>School Settings</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li>ABC</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</template>
```

seems unable to find out `permissionvar.root_permission_name` , i don't know why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, when you click on the "Get from LocalStorage" button, you get a string from the storage and not an array. So you need to parse it before trying to use it in ngFor:

```
getData(){
  this.LocalStorageData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("DEMO data"));
}
```

See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/aumB4mMNVlV9TK5KDjoF?p=preview.

Answer (score 4):

- http://plnkr.co/edit/7ff3o9oDhjAbt8yd3uST?p=preview

```
getData(){
    this.LocalStorageData =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("DEMO data"));  //stringify data needs to be parsed to json.
}
```

In addition to that, to show json object into HTML you can use `{{jsonobject|json}}` [jsonPipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/JsonPipe-class.html) as shown in demo.