# Angular2 ngFor: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm having difficulty overcoming the "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'" error that seems to be really common with Angular2, and I'm hoping someone has encountered something similar.

Here's the (anonymized) JSON coming from my service, which is really simple:

```
[
    {
        "item_id": 1,
        "item_type": 2,
        "item_name": "Item 1",
        "item_description": "First item"
    },
    {
        "item_id": 2,
        "item_type": 4,
        "item_name": "Item 2",
        "item_description": "Second item"
    }
]
```

And here's the contents of my class, service, and component that describes these objects:

```js
// item.ts
export class Item {
    item_id: number;
    item_type: number;
    item_name: string;
    item_description: string;
}

//item.service.ts snippet
getItems(): Promise<Item[]> {
    return this.http.get('http://apiurl', { withCredentials: true })
    .toPromise()
    .then((response) => {
        let body = response.json();
        return body as Item[];
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
}

//item.component.ts snippet
items: Item[];

getItems(): void { // Function that calls the item service
    this.itemService
    .getItems()
    .then((items) => {
        console.log(items); // I use this to verify that I'm getting an array.
        this.items = items;
    });
}
```

And finally, the ngFor component:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items">
        <i class="fa fa-database"></i> {{item.item_name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm not seeing anything wrong with any part of this. The retrieved data definitely does reach the item component, which means my imports are correct, and what shows up in my console.log is definitely an array, with the `__proto__:Array[0]` property and everything. It even looks identical to what gets output if I console log the Angular tutorial Heroes app. Yet it simply will not iterate over the array, insisting that it's an object.

What am I doing wrong? Is ngFor just broken?

**Edit**
Here is the complete (anonymized) class, with unrelated bits removed:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Headers, Response, Http, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Item } from '../../classes/item/item';
import { ItemService } from '../../services/item/item.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-items',
    templateUrl: 'items.component.html'
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
    items: Item[] = [];

    constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private itemService: ItemService
    ) { }

    getItems(): void {
        console.log(this.items);
        this.itemService
        .getItems()
        .then((items) => {
            console.log(items);
            this.items = Array.from(items);
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getItems();
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**:

I got it! And I think it might be a bug in Angular2. Above, I sanitized my code by using a generic variable name called "items." But in the real, production code, the variable is called "entities." And for the whole time, I've had it named like that. On a whim, I changed the name of the variable to "testentities," and it worked!

So just to make sure, I tested with multiple variations, and it worked every time. Then I changed it back to "entities," and the error reappeared. It seems to be a reserved variable of some kind.

I'll rigorously test this out, and if it is consistently reproducible, I'll report it on the bug tracker.

Comment: The syntax looks good, so it must be a typo or something, because I don't see any issues with whats posted. Make sure all variables are spelled correctly and object properties are spelled correctly. There is also this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6392 and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401069/cannot-find-a-differ-supporting-object-error-angular2

Comment: @Sasquatch3o3 I double-checked the variable names, they're all fine. And if I comment out the ngFor template, the component loads without any errors.

Comment: Ooo, just discovered something that might help. If I comment out the `this.items = items` line in the component (leaving the Item[] array empty), ngFor *still* throws the error. So it's seeing `items: Item[]` without any changes as an object, not an array. Ideas?

Comment: ok cool, let me take a look again

Comment: @Sasquatch3o3 Take a look at what it seems to be. The real name of the variable is "entities," and I think it may be internally reserved!

Comment: Oh wow, well good job, from the sound of it you may have figured it out! I guess I won't ever use `entities` in my ng2 apps in the near future.

Comment: If you submit a report, could you include a link to it in your question?

Comment: @cartant Real life has prevented me from spending the time on this that I need to today, but when I've got the time, I guarantee the bug report will be here.

Comment: No worries. It will be interesting to see a Plunker if you build one for the bug report. A quick search of the GitHub repo for `entities` doesn't reveal anything suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

**item.service.ts** snippet

```
getItems(): Promise<Item[]> {
    return this.http.get('http://apiurl', { withCredentials: true })
    .toPromise()
    .then((response) => {
        let body = response.json();
        return body;
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**item.component.ts** snippet

```
items: Item[] = []; // For whatever reason it thinks this is an Object

getItems(): void { // Function that calls the item service
    //this.items = Array.from(this.items);
    this.itemService.getItems().then(items => this.items = items);
}
```

### [UPDATE]

Alight, you have exhausted my debugging resources, so I will take it to the basics,

Angular 2 [HTTP Client](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html) is where they show you how to make a `GET` request. Then [HERE](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#promises) is the Promise based setup.

So going off of that this is what yours should look like.

**item.service.ts** snippet

```
getItems(): Promise<Item[]> {
    return this.http.get('http://apiurl', { withCredentials: true })
    .toPromise()
    .then(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res.json();
  return body || { };
}
private handleError (error: any) {
  // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
  // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
  let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
    error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
  console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
  return Promise.reject(errMsg);
}
```

**item.component.ts**

```
items: Item[] = [];

getItems(): void {
  this.itemService.getItems().then(items => this.items = items);
}
```

### **UPDATE #2**

It sounds like the OP figured out his problem and it had to do with the name of one of the variables, it would appear that a variable named `entites` could cause Angular 2 to break.

> "But in the real, production code, the variable is called "entities." And for the whole time, I've had it named like that. On a whim, I changed the name of the variable to "testentities," and it worked!
>
> So just to make sure, I tested with multiple variations, and it worked every time. Then I changed it back to "entities," and the error reappeared."

```
entities: any{};
```

Comment: It's a good idea, but I'm afraid it didn't work. The `items: Item[] = [];` part looks like it ought to force items to be an array, but the exact same error persists.

Comment: @DamonKaswell Did you have the `Array.from(items)` part in there?

Comment: Yes, it's in there. But my biggest concern right now is that even if I don't populate the array at all, ngFor still sees it as an object.

Comment: @DamonKaswell Okay put a breakpoint on this line `console.log(items); // I use this to verify that I'm getting an array.` and when you hit that line, type in the Developer console this `this.items instanceof Array` AND `items instanceof Array`, they both should be true statements. I know you think that `this.items` is an object but this will validate what it is. Arrays in Javascript are just Objects that use numbers instead of strings

Comment: OK, I think we're getting warmer. That didn't work, because the error is already thrown by the time it gets to retrieving data. So I put a breakpoint right at `items: Item[] = [];`. Interestingly, if I run `this.items instanceof Array` then, it returns false!

Comment: @DamonKaswell Okay cool cool thats good, give this a shot too, in the `getItems(): void` function just before the service call, put this `Array.from(this.items)` and check that it is an `instanceof Array` right after that but before the service call, it should return `true`. If, the error still persists, if you don't mind, could you post the component that has `items: Item[]`, you may anonymize it but I think it would be helpful if I could see the class.

Comment: @DamonKaswell check the post, I edited it to show what it should look like and what you should do to try and make `this.items` an array prior to making the service call

Comment: I've posted the current version of the class above. Also, at the breakpoint where getItems() starts, you're right about `Array.from(this.items) instanceof Array` returning true. So I'm deeply confused, now.

Comment: @DamonKaswell Excellent! Now insert into `getItems(): void` this `this.items = Array.from(this.items);` right before the service call check the post I will edit it so it matches what it should look like

Comment: Done. I've added breakpoints at multiple steps of the way now, and here's where it stands: `Array.from(this.items) instanceof Array` returns true at every point until the service runs. At that point - the breakpoint on `console.log(items)` inside the service - I suddenly get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of null`, which is really bizarre. How in the world could this.items suddenly be null?

Comment: @DamonKaswell check the post, I made a change to the function in your `service` and to the `getItems(): void` function in the component

Comment: Hate to say it, but that's a no-go. In fact, when I switched the declaration of items from `items: Item[] = []` to `items: Item[]`, this.items is null inside the `getItems(): void` function. When I include the = [] part, it's not null.

Comment: @DamonKaswell Ok you and your code win, I have exhausted my debugging techniques and I have edited the post to reflect what they have on the Angular 2 site, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html, I would suggest just taking it back to the simple start and work back up. I have edited the post to show what your code would look like if you followed the Angular 2 example. Maybe you should follow their example and then compare yours to mine and see if we come up with the same thing

Comment: Thank you for giving it the ol' college try! I'm in the middle of refactoring the code per the Angular 2 example, I'll pore over those docs, and if I figure this thing out, I'll post an update.

Comment: @DamonKaswell For sure man, when you do figure it out, please post, I am very interested to see!